# Can't generate bootstrap file in Symfony 2.1.1

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I've got an application written for Symfony 2.0 and I've started migrating it into Symfony 2.1. I've successfully installed all the dependencies with composer but a script fails...

```
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]                                     
  An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file.
```

Any clue? I'm completely lost and I've googled it but I've only found a post in a forum with people having the same problem as me...

Comment: Does Composer has the rights to right your `app/` folder?

Comment: I use PHP 5.4.4 and I executed composer with `sudo` so I think I've got enough rights..

Comment: I have the same problem, are you using MAMP by any chance?

Comment: Yep. I use MAMP, but it is not related with this problem. See my answer as I finally found the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that [the manual is not clear](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.1/UPGRADE.md). It tells you to execute `composer.phar install` before telling that symfony-standard files need to be replaced.

So now you have to replace

- `AppKernel.php`,
- `AppCache.php` and
- `autoload.php` (and remove odd files)

and update your `config.yml` file with the given tips.